# dbtvault error when running the model ERROR: Runtime Error Could not find profile named 'dbtvault_snowflake_demo'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, dbt

I am quite new to dbtvault and I was wondering where should I put the profile.yml file?
I am trying to run the sample code which is in official docs (https://github.com/Datavault-UK/dbtvault-snowflakeDemo/releases).when I try to run the sql scripts, I have the error shown below [image]

I tried running dbt run --help, it is said the default directory to look into is C:\Users\Username.dbt and I tried placing the profile.yml file in that location. But it doesnt seem to work.
Could anyone suggest me on what needs to be done here ?

Answer (score 0):

When calling dbt from the command line, dbt will parse your `dbt_Project.yml` and obtain the profile name.

dbt will search for the `profiles.yml` file in the current working directory. If not found, it defaults to the `~/.dbt/` directory.

> I was wondering where should I put the profile.yml file?

The default path for profiles.yml is `~/.dbt/`